# Expandable List - update a TextView in the second row

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

[image]

I have used an expandable list to accomplish the above design. However I have issues in doing the following.

The vacancy list should load depending on the value selected from the Account list. 
Also when An account is selected by default the first name in the vacancy list should be selected and the name of the vacancy should replace **test sarah**

I have completed the above. How ever the vacancy name change only occurs when I click & expand the Vacancy list where as it should happen as I change the Account Name. Is there any way to do this ? I really need a solution on this. I have almost tried all references in the internet.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> listOptionsHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<>();
    private FontUtils fontUtils;
    private TextView selectedChild;
    private View selectedView;
    private String value = null;
    private AccountsViewModel accountsViewModel;
    private VacancyViewModel vacancyViewModel;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    private View getSelectedView() {
        return selectedView;
    }

    public void setSelectedView(View selectedView) {
        this.selectedView = selectedView;
    }

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.fontUtils = new FontUtils(context);
        this.accountsViewModel = new AccountsViewModel(context);
        this.vacancyViewModel = new VacancyViewModel(context, Validators.selectedAccountId);
        this.listOptionsHeader.add("Accounts");
        this.listOptionsHeader.add("Vacancies");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listOptionsHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_header_layout, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        fontUtils.changeFontOfTextViewtoOpenSansSemiBold(lblListHeader);
        TextView selectedChild2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected_child);
        fontUtils.changeFontOfTextViewtoOpenSansLight(selectedChild2);
        if (value == null) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                selectedChild2.setText(Validators.selectedAccountName);
            } else if (groupPosition == 1) {
                selectedChild2.setText(Validators.selectedVacancyName);
            } else if (groupPosition == 2) {
                selectedChild2.setText(Validators.selectedStatus.toString());
            }
        }
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        convertView.setTag("HeaderView-" + headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        long groupId = getCombinedGroupId(getGroupId(groupPosition));
        int buttonId = 0;
        if (groupId != 0) {
            String xxx = String.valueOf(getCombinedGroupId(getGroupId(groupPosition)));
            buttonId = Integer.parseInt(xxx.substring(0, 5));
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_child_radio_layout, parent, false);
        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
        radioGroup.removeAllViews();
        radioGroup.setFocusable(false);

        if (groupPosition == 0) {
            List<Accounts> accountsList = accountsViewModel.getAccountsList();
            List<String> accountNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int x = 0; x < accountsList.size(); x++) {

                accountNames.add(accountsList.get(x).getName());
            }
            listDataChild.put(listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition), accountNames);
            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size()];
            radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
            for (int i = 0; i < listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size(); i++) {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
                final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, i);
                rb[i].setText(childText);
                rb[i].setId(i + buttonId);
                rb[i].setTag(accountsList.get(i).getId());
                if (rb[i].getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Validators.selectedFilterAccountId)) {
                    rb[i].setChecked(true);
                }
                fontUtils.changeFontOfRadioButtontoOpenSansRegular(rb[i]);
                rb[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letter_small));
                radioGroup.addView(rb[i]);
                final int finalI = i;
                rb[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (getSelectedView() != null) {
                            selectedChild = (TextView) getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.selected_child);
                            selectedChild.setText(rb[finalI].getText());
                            value = rb[finalI].getText().toString();
                            Validators.selectedRadioId = rb[finalI].getId();
                            Validators.selectedFilterAccountId = rb[finalI].getTag().toString();
                            Validators.selectedAccountName = rb[finalI].getText().toString();
                            vacancyViewModel = new VacancyViewModel(context, Validators.selectedFilterAccountId);
                            Validators.isAccountChanged = true;
                            getExpandableListView().collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else if (groupPosition == 1) {
            List<Vacancy> vacancyList = vacancyViewModel.getVacancyList();
            List<String> vacancyNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int x = 0; x < vacancyList.size(); x++) {

                vacancyNames.add(vacancyList.get(x).getVacancyName());
            }
            listDataChild.put(listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition), vacancyNames);
            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size()];
            radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
            for (int i = 0; i < listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size(); i++) {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
                final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, i);
                rb[i].setText(childText);
                rb[i].setId(i + buttonId);
                rb[i].setTag(vacancyList.get(i).getId());
                if (Validators.isAccountChanged) {
                    rb[0].setChecked(true);
                    selectedChild = (TextView) getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.selected_child);
                    Validators.selectedVacancyName = rb[0].getText().toString();
                    selectedChild.setText(rb[0].getText());
                    Validators.selectedFilterVacancyId = rb[0].getTag().toString();
                } else {
                    if (rb[i].getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Validators.selectedFilterVacancyId)) {
                        rb[i].setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
                fontUtils.changeFontOfRadioButtontoOpenSansRegular(rb[i]);
                rb[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letter_small));
                radioGroup.addView(rb[i]);
                final int finalI = i;
                rb[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (getSelectedView() != null) {
                            selectedChild = (TextView) getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.selected_child);
                            System.out.println(selectedChild.getId());
                            selectedChild.setText(rb[finalI].getText());
                            value = rb[finalI].getText().toString();
                            Validators.selectedRadioId = rb[finalI].getId();
                            Validators.selectedFilterVacancyId = rb[finalI].getTag().toString();
                            Validators.selectedVacancyName = rb[finalI].getText().toString();
                            Validators.isAccountChanged = false;
                            getExpandableListView().collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public ExpandableListView getExpandableListView() {
        return expandableListView;
    }

    public void setExpandableListView(ExpandableListView expandableListView) {
        this.expandableListView = expandableListView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add the Adapter Class here

Comment: @Venky Hi I have added the adapter class. Please check